# Redis server crash on MacOS 11

Tags: redis

I have installed redis using the Rosetta terminal but when I run "redis-server" I get this error. I am on the new Mac Book Pro 2020 with Apple Silicon.

```
redis-server



42116:C 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.620 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo 42116:C 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.620 # Redis version=6.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=42116, just started 42116:C 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.620 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.620 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 2560).


=== REDIS BUG REPORT START: Cut & paste starting from here === 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.622 # Redis 6.0.9 crashed by signal: 11, si_code: 2 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.622 # Crashed running the instruction at: 0x7fff20371430 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.622 # Accessing address: 0x3046d2000 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.622 # Killed by PID: 0, UID: 0 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.622 # Failed assertion: <no assertion failed> (<no file>:0)

------ STACK TRACE ------ EIP: 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff20371430 _platform_memset$VARIANT$Rosetta + 108

Backtrace: 0   redis-server                        0x00000001000e4bb7 logStackTrace + 110 1   redis-server                        0x00000001000e4fd5 sigsegvHandler + 271 2   libsystem_platform.dylib   0x00007fff2036ed7d _sigtramp + 29 3   libsystem_malloc.dylib           0x00007fff201547aa tiny_free_no_lock + 1116 4   redis-server           0x00000001001350c3 luaD_call + 97 5   ???                              0x0000000032aaaba2 0x0 + 850045858

------ INFO OUTPUT ------
# Server redis_version:6.0.9 redis_git_sha1:00000000 redis_git_dirty:0 redis_build_id:ec508acaad782189 redis_mode:standalone os:Darwin 20.1.0 x86_64 arch_bits:64 multiplexing_api:kqueue atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin gcc_version:4.2.1 process_id:42116 run_id:3456c4d545624d4cbf42d4b85695b8f4cb6ce250 tcp_port:6379 uptime_in_seconds:0 uptime_in_days:0 hz:10 configured_hz:10 lru_clock:12150112 executable:/Users/leonardo/Dropbox/dev/redis/redis-stable/redis-server config_file: io_threads_active:0

# Clients connected_clients:0 client_recent_max_input_buffer:0 client_recent_max_output_buffer:0 blocked_clients:0 tracking_clients:0 clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory used_memory:1019360 used_memory_human:995.47K used_memory_rss:0 used_memory_rss_human:0B used_memory_peak:1019360 used_memory_peak_human:995.47K used_memory_peak_perc:inf% used_memory_overhead:0 used_memory_startup:0 used_memory_dataset:1019360 used_memory_dataset_perc:100.00% allocator_allocated:0 allocator_active:0 allocator_resident:0 total_system_memory:8589934592 total_system_memory_human:8.00G used_memory_lua:37888 used_memory_lua_human:37.00K used_memory_scripts:0 used_memory_scripts_human:0B number_of_cached_scripts:0 maxmemory:0 maxmemory_human:0B maxmemory_policy:noeviction allocator_frag_ratio:nan allocator_frag_bytes:0 allocator_rss_ratio:nan allocator_rss_bytes:0 rss_overhead_ratio:nan rss_overhead_bytes:0 mem_fragmentation_ratio:nan mem_fragmentation_bytes:0 mem_not_counted_for_evict:0 mem_replication_backlog:0 mem_clients_slaves:0 mem_clients_normal:0 mem_aof_buffer:0 mem_allocator:libc active_defrag_running:0 lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence loading:0 rdb_changes_since_last_save:0 rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0 rdb_last_save_time:1605985632 rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1 rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1 rdb_last_cow_size:0 aof_enabled:0 aof_rewrite_in_progress:0 aof_rewrite_scheduled:0 aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1 aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1 aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok aof_last_write_status:ok aof_last_cow_size:0 module_fork_in_progress:0 module_fork_last_cow_size:0

# Stats total_connections_received:0 total_commands_processed:0 instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0 total_net_input_bytes:0 total_net_output_bytes:0 instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00 instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00 rejected_connections:0 sync_full:0 sync_partial_ok:0 sync_partial_err:0 expired_keys:0 expired_stale_perc:0.00 expired_time_cap_reached_count:0 expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:0 evicted_keys:0 keyspace_hits:0 keyspace_misses:0 pubsub_channels:0 pubsub_patterns:0 latest_fork_usec:0 migrate_cached_sockets:0 slave_expires_tracked_keys:0 active_defrag_hits:0 active_defrag_misses:0 active_defrag_key_hits:0 active_defrag_key_misses:0 tracking_total_keys:0 tracking_total_items:0 tracking_total_prefixes:0 unexpected_error_replies:0 total_reads_processed:0 total_writes_processed:0 io_threaded_reads_processed:0 io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication role:master connected_slaves:0 master_replid:b00cc4f1203a9a29b81236248b7ebc68c567f4ad master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 master_repl_offset:0 second_repl_offset:-1 repl_backlog_active:0 repl_backlog_size:1048576 repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0 repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU used_cpu_sys:0.004632 used_cpu_user:0.007445 used_cpu_sys_children:0.000000 used_cpu_user_children:0.000000

# Modules

# Commandstats

# Cluster cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace

------ CLIENT LIST OUTPUT ------

------ REGISTERS ------ 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 #  RAX:00000003046d1c80 RBX:0000000000000013 RCX:00000003046d2000 RDX:00007f9b90d338ae RDI:00000003046d1c18 RSI:0000000000000000 RBP:00000003046d1a40 RSP:00000003046d1858 R8 :0000000000000000 R9 :00000003046d1910 R10:00000001001507b3 R11:ffffffffffffffff R12:00000003046d1ae0 R13:00000000000000ff R14:0000000100151127 R15:0000000100181740 RIP:00007fff20371430 EFL:0000000000000202 CS :000000000000002b FS:0000000000000000  GS:0000000000000000 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1867) -> 0000000108c36a00 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1866) -> 0000000000000006 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1865) -> 0000000000000000 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1864)
-> 0000000000002800 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1863) -> 0000000000000000 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1862) -> 00007fff20152020 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1861) -> 000000010015fbca 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1860) -> 00000001000f34d6 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185f) -> 00000003046d19d0 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185e) -> 00007f9e85400000 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185d)
-> 0000000100152d38 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185c) -> 00000000000018eb 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185b) -> 000000010014dbcd 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d185a) -> 00000003046d1c18 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1859) -> 00007f9e85407da0 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # (00000003046d1858) -> 0000000100103ebb

------ MODULES INFO OUTPUT ------

------ DUMPING CODE AROUND EIP ------ Symbol: _platform_memset$VARIANT$Rosetta (base: 0x7fff203713c4) Module: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib (base 0x7fff2036b000) $ xxd
-r -p /tmp/dump.hex /tmp/dump.bin $ objdump --adjust-vma=0x7fff203713c4 -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 /tmp/dump.bin
------ 42116:M 21 Nov 2020 20:07:12.623 # dump of function (hexdump of 236 bytes): 81e6ff00000048b90101010101010101480faff14889f94883fa400f82360100004881fa008000000f82a00000000faef0480fc337480fc37708480fc37710480fc37718480fc37720480fc37728480fc37730480fc37738488d4f404883e1c04801fa488d41404829c27631480fc331480fc37108480fc37110480fc37118480fc37120480fc37128480fc37130480fc371384883c1404883ea4077cf4801d1480fc331480fc37108480fc37110480fc37118480fc37120480fc37128480fc37130480fc371380faef84889f8c3488937488977084889771048897718488977204889772848897730488977

=== REDIS BUG REPORT END. Make sure to include from START to END. ===

       Please report the crash by opening an issue on github:

           http://github.com/redis/redis/issues

  Suspect RAM error? Use redis-server --test-memory to verify it.

zsh: segmentation fault  redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory overflow can cause the Redis service to crash. During peak time, the Redis service may require more memory than what is currently allocated.

To check current configuration and used memory, run the following command in the CLI. It checks for used memory, maxmemory, evicted keys, and Redis up time in days:

`redis-cli -p REDIS_PORT -h REDIS_HOST info | egrep --color "(role|used_memory_peak|maxmemory|evicted_keys|uptime_in_days)"`

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]: Per the latest on that redis Github issue, a fix was merged.
You can either build it locally from their latest master or wait for the next public release (current version is 6.0.9), which will likely include the fix.

I believe the Redis team is currently still working on support here:

https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8062

Per that link, you might be able to run Redis under `sudo`